# User passwords printed on paperwork at a dental office?

Tags: passwords, compliance, sensitive-data-exposure

My dental office just printed my user-defined password (not a first or one-time password) to their portal on some checkout paperwork.

I asked on [Law.stackexchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/45727/is-it-a-hipaa-violation-for-a-dentist-office-to-print-a-patients-password-on-pa) and it doesn't sound like this is a HIPAA violation, but I am really curious if this violates other regulations or goes against known best practices, as it seems really bad security-wise.

It doesn't feel right that they can even see my password.

Any thoughts / resources much appreciated.

Comment: What geographic area are you in? US? EU?

Answer (score 1):

If it is the password that you generated and that you use to access their portal, it is unacceptable that they know it. How do they know the password? 
Did you provide it *directly* (verbally or otherwise) outside the sign-up process on the portal?
If not, this means that their portal database save users passwords in clear and they have full access to them, this, at least in EU, 
can conflict with new privacy and electronic data processing rules: [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation). I don't know what your nation is, but even if it were outside the European Union, I am sure that such behavior would violate some law.

Comment: @schroeder 
you're almost right in saying that GDPR is not  restrictive. However I work as a sysadmin in a company and our privacy consultant has expressed  more than a 
perplexity for a db that stored sensitive data in clear. They don't make you 
contraventions for this but, if tomorrow someone accesses the database and takes the data, the responsibility is yours and things can take an unpleasant turn for you.

Comment: Much better phrasing. Thanks. The #1 rule of GDPR: "It depends".

Comment: @schroeder thanks to you for pointing out :)

Answer (score 1):

Does it violate best practices? Absolutely.

Passwords are meant to be stored in a hashed form, which means that they should not be able to work out what your password is to be able to print it off anywhere. This has been a standard for decades.

There may be privacy regulations that might have an opinion on the practice, too, depending on your jurisdiction.

The bigger problem is trying to talk to your dentist office about it as no one there is likely to be able to understand either the security or privacy issues and nuances. If you express your concerns, I suspect the response would include some notion that all info on the portal is a copy of info that they already have access to. So, it would come down to the issue that it is printed off, and that the admin of the portal also has access to the data, and that requires an understanding of the nuances of security or privacy.